# Loading different layouts for a fragment at runtime in onConfigurationChange

Tags: android, layout, configuration, fragment

I have an activity which has an fragment attached. Let's say `FragmentA` is attached to the activity `TestActivity`. 
Now `FragmentA` has a `layoutA` which has some **UI elements** like *TextView, Button and one more sublayout layoutb included in its layout* 
    .

Now I want to programatically handle the `onconfigurationchange` for the `FragmentA` and only **reload the layoutb elements**.

I tried the following change in `onConfigChange` in the `FragmentA`:

```
private View mySubLayoutView;

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
    mySubLayoutView.invalidate();
}
```

I assume calling **invalidate would reload the layout from accordingly**. But it's still not reloading.

I have **created the layoutb** file in both **layout-land and layout-port** folders.